# How to determine if an index is "USING HASH"?

Tags: mysql

I've got this table definition in MySQL 5.6.39:

```
CREATE TABLE `_fulltexttest` (
  `hello` text NOT NULL,
  `bar` varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
  `baz` varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `whatev2` (`baz`) USING HASH,
  KEY `whatev` (`bar`) USING HASH,
  KEY `baz` (`baz`) USING HASH,
  KEY `baz_2` (`baz`) COMMENT 'bacon',
  FULLTEXT KEY `hello` (`hello`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

As you can see, a few of the indexes have `USING HASH`.

However, when I try:

```
 show indexes from _fulltexttest in mydb;
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb' and TABLE_NAME='_fulltexttest'
```

Neither shows "HASH" anywhere in there. The `INDEX_TYPE` is `BTREE`.

But if I do a `SHOW TABLE`, it shows up in the definition, so clearly it must be saved *somewhere*.

What query can I run to get the full index definition, including the `USING HASH` part?

Comment: Can you add the output from `SHOW CREATE _fulltexttest` to your question?  This is really strange, because InnoDB should support hash indices.

Comment: Same here, tested everything it the result is the same, table table is created, but the index type is shown as btree. utterly odd (10.1.13-MariaDB)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Here the show create command shows the create statement exactly equals typed (whit the hash index type).

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, of course you are right.  This is strange.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That **is** the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE _fulltexttest`

Comment: Even stranger, I did another test, create the table without the indexes and then run the create index statement `create index idx_test on _fulltexttest2 (baz) using hash;` and the index type is shown as btree. When I execute the show create table for this new table it shows the column with the 'using hash' that's reaaaaaally weird

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The thing is **I** am testing on mariadb OP need to confirm if it is the case or not

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: _"InnoDB should support hash indices"_ Can you confirm why you think this is so? I cannot corroborate this from the documentation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [From this Stack DBA post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/why-does-mysql-not-have-hash-indices-on-myisam-or-innodb) I can confirm your answer.  MySQL's documentation does not do a good job here IMHO.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Wellll on the one hand there is a table (lol) that specifically tells us what we need to know. On the other hand, it was _not_ easy to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done the right thing for determining whether the index is using hash.

The answer is: it isn't.

The documentation for MySQL 5.6 says [they haven't implemented it for InnoDB at all yet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html#create-index-storage-engine-index-types).

Comment: I'm actually using MySQL 5.6.39... but I think we *tried* converting to MariaDB at some point in time and then back again. Maybe it got wonky...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that was me

Comment: @mpen Dammit, got you confused with a commenter.

Comment: Read those comments again.

Comment: Great just found that also in another part of the Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html#create-index-storage-engine-index-types

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Good find. Stealing it :)

Comment: Be my guest! Great catch!

Comment: @JorgeCampos Oh... well, I guess that answers it then. Thanks! Strange it shows in the "SHOW CREATE" though.

Comment: @mpen: `SHOW CREATE` shows you how you created the table. It doesn't rewrite it.

Comment: I created the table in pieces, not as a single statement. It's piecing together various strings somehow.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, with that I disagree (at least for mariadb). I tested creating the table without the index and then using the create index statement, and it rewrites it with the using hash.

Comment: The point remains it is reflecting what you asked for, not what you got. Part of your table definition is "I'd like to use `HASH` indexes please", and that is _still true_, even though the request was never satisfied.